# How did Fudge find out about Harry heading to Leaky Cauldron?

Tags: harry-potter

One thing that always bothered me about Prisoner of Azkeban: Harry arrived on Knight Bus to the Leaky Cauldron, and was met there by Minister of Magic Fudge.

How in the world would Fudge know to await for Harry at the Cauldron?

Comment: To advance the plot?

Comment: He asked Dumbledore.

Comment: Mmm, Magic Fudge.

Answer (score 9):

Harry maintains certain routines. For example:

> ‘I *always* stay at Hogwarts for the Christmas and Easter holidays,’ he said, ‘and I don’t ever want to go back to Privet Drive.’
>   <sub>*Prisoner of Azkaban* - page 48 - Bloomsbury - chapter 3, *The Knight Bus*</sub>

He goes back to Privet Drive for the summer holidays and usually ends up at the Burrow before heading to Diagon Alley to pick up his school supplies.

I think it's important to remember that the Leaky Cauldron is the first magical place Harry ever encountered. It is the portal to Diagon Alley, a place Harry goes every year prior to the new school term starting. Knowing Harry needed school supplies, Fudge could have easily anticipated where Harry ended up. I'm guessing that the Minister for Magic was kept apprised of Harry Potter's comings and goings during Harry's entire stint at Hogwarts.

Hagrid tells Harry that the Leaky Cauldron is a famous place. What better a place for a famous wizard to show up at than a famous one.

> ‘This is it,’ said Hagrid, coming to a halt, ‘the Leaky Cauldron. It’s a famous place.’
>   *Philosopher's Stone* - page 53 - Bloomsbury - chapter 5, *Diagon Alley*

Essentially the Leaky Cauldron is the barrier between the Muggle and wizarding worlds. It leads to Diagon Alley, a hugely important part of the wizarding world. It's famous; Harry's famous. I think it's a very logical place for Fudge to anticipate Harry's arrival on the Knight Bus.

Comment: "What better a place for a famous wizard to show up at than a famous one." - it's showing up there with Gilderoy Lockhart.

Answer (score 0):

How many more wizarding places does Harry know? It's the Leaky Cauldron leading to Diagon Alley, King's Cross, and I can't recall any more. And why would Harry go to King's Cross, when the Leaky Cauldron is also an Inn? (I doubt the Knight Bus stops at the Burrow.)

Comment: You're kidding, right? The Knight Bus can instantly teleport anywhere it doesn't have to worry about conventional silliness like fixed bus stops. If it can pick Harry up at a more-or-less random spot near Privet Drive, it can certainly drop him off at The Burrow.